# How to make a navbar that does not change in height with screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This is my navbar. I'm new to Bootstrap and its driving me crazy. All I want is a simple navbar that doesn't change its height with screen changes, but is horizontally responsive. This one always seems to change navbar height below 768px.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="{%url 'index'%}" class="navbar-left"><h5>blumury</h5></a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ">
      <li><a href="{%url 'index'%}"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 16px;">home</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 16px;">vibration</i></a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 16px;">settings <span class='caret'></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="{%url 'profile_view' pk=request.user.id%}">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Write Block</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Series</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="{%url 'signout'%}">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZbgrb

Comment: Thanks! Thats almost what I'm trying to do. But I don't need the right nav items to collapse after breakpoint to a hamburger icon. I've made the icons really small so that they can continue to be responsive horizontally without collapsing in small screens. I don't know how to do that. Tried overriding nav collapse, and floating nav items right so that the everything remains in a line. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify CSS code, not HTML one, you're only showing HTML above, which refer to bootstrap files, you can usually find them inside of the

```
<head>
<!-- This is a comment -->
</head>
```

So you're trying to find the solution in the wrong code/file, try adding or changing css using the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Let me know if you have others questions !

Comment: Yes. I was asking for a way to override Bootstrap's css so that I can avoid Bootstrap's collapse breakpoint at 768px. That way the right nav items are still visible in smaller screens without collapsing.